Command to show several previous values for a git branch?
When I botched a rebase, I can use main@{2} to look at previous commits pointed to by a branch. That helps me find where the branch was pointing before my rebase. However, it's often not the first one. Is there an easy way to get an overview of multiple previous positions of the branch?
I could script it with something like:
for a in `seq 1 4` ; do git show -s --oneline main@{$a} ; done

But maybe git has a better way?

Ah, I remembered reflog!
git log --reflog --graph --oneline

It generates output that includes orphaned commits:
* 9e9b66ec4c (HEAD -> bind-mouse) Input: Minor cleanup for exclusive checking
* c7df65d393 (main) Input: Use ANYMOD
* 4337ab9c8f Input: Minor cleanup for exclusive checking
| * 65a5a3e994 fixup! Input: Minor cleanup for exclusive checking
| | * 94c40dcb45 wip: bind mouse buttons
| |/
| * 4aeff900e9 Input: Use ANYMOD
| * fbefc98455 Input: Minor cleanup for exclusive checking
|/
| * 79ad948a48 wip: bind mouse buttons
|/
* 9e93fff738 (mine/main) UI: Create scroller widget
* 75b48f680b UI: Make alignment exact

From there, it's easy to see that my bind-mouse change is either 94c40dcb45 or 79ad948a48 -- probably the former since it includes more commits.
